# Enqueue scripts to a specific header-<name>.php?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I've multiple header files (header-name.php), they are mainly being used by different custom post types. 
Is there any way to enqueue script to only a specific header?

At this moment I'm targeting it with conditional tag like if `( 'MYPOSTTYPE' == get_post_type() )` but I'm looking for a better alternative.

do we have something like `is_header('name')`?

Answer (score 1):

You load the header file probably with `get_header()`. There is a hook you can use: `'get_header'`. You get the called header name as parameter.

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'wpse_54865_conditional_enqueue' );

function wpse_54865_conditional_enqueue( $name )
{
    if ( 'my_custom_header_name' === $name )
    {
        // register your script loading function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action is part of the `wp_head` hook, so the enqueue process isn't really tied to header.php. It's also the appropriate way to enqueue scripts and styles. You could possibly switch to the `is_singlular ( 'MYPOSTTYPE' )` conditional tag, but I'm not sure that's really better.

You could set a global variable before the `wp_head()` function in your header.php's and then test for that variable to decide which scripts to enqueue.