# How to load different CSS in different Header?

Tags: theme-development, templates

I have two different files for the header in my theme. These are `header.php` and `header-full.php`.

How can I load different CSS in different headers?

I enqueue my CSS files in `function.php` like this:

[image]

Comment: use `wp_enqueue_style` only in the header file

Comment: Use hook [`get_header`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_header) please take a look [@toscho answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54878), you have the same issue with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enqueue style depending on a template filename:

```
if('header.php' == basename( get_page_template() ) { // check the template file name
    // enqueue header.php style here
}

if('header-full.php' == basename( get_page_template() ) { // check the template file name
    // enqueue header-full.php style here
}
```

`wp_enqueue_style` already registers a style so you don't need to register a style before enqueueing it except in very special cases. See [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: I think you missed, `header-full.php` is not page a template :D

Comment: thanks, I will use something llike this:  if( $CurrentTemplate == 'Full Header'){ //enque CSS for header.php }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your enqueued files (probably a good idea [as outlined here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49098/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wp-enqueue-script)), then - yes - you could add some conditionals in your functions.php such as:

```
if(some conditional) {
// enqueue header.php style here
}

if(some other conditional) { 
// enqueue header-full.php style here
}
```

Or, you don't have to enqueue them at all. You could just reference them in your two header files. Eg.in header.php put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and in header-full.php put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/css/full-header.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score -1):

One simple way of doing it is by using a php function called "basename".

If you have 2 header headerone.php, headertwo.php  you can load different resources depending upon the name of the page you are viewing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'headerone.php'){ ?>
     <link href="/includes/headerone.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
   <?php }
   elseif(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'headertwo.php'){
   ?>
    <link href="/includes/headertwo.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
   <?php } ?>
 </head>
<body>
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, but i think that is not the best way, based on wordpress doc, we must enqueue it, like this article : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/