# How to load different css file for different pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I have several different pages. Every one of them has different css links. Rather than the css links all items are same in the head element of those pages.
I need to shift those head element to `header.php` so that I can include head using `get_header()`.

So How can I load different css file for different pages? I have around 20 different pages, so load file after condition check is bit messy to me.
Is there any better approach to do than [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222565/how-to-load-different-css-in-different-header)?
If possible suggest me to solve this problem using custom plugin?

**page 1:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/one.css" />
     .......
 </head>
```

**page 2:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/two.css" />
     .......
 </head>
```

Comment: Did you test if this really is benficial? I would presume combining them and having the file in cache would be faster than requesting 20 different files

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using [conditionals](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) inside the function enqueuing your styles.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'global', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    if ( is_page(5) ) {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'page-five', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/page-five-styles.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

If you wanted more control over both the markup of your page and the CSS files you load, you could use WordPress' template hierarchy and create a page template or something more specific like `page-5.php`. Calling `wp_enqueue_scripts` from within these template files only loads the assets for those pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do it in your template you can do the following.

You can learn more about the is_page function here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <?php if ( is_page(1) ): //Change this number to id of page ?> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/one.css" />
     <?php endif; if ( is_page(2) ): //Change this number to id of page ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/two.css" />
     <?php endif; ?>
 .......
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<?php global $post;
if( $post->ID == 346) { ?>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/one.css" />
<?php } ?>
    elseif ( $post->ID == 342){ ?> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/two.css" />
         <?php } else{ //Change this number to id of page ?>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/three.css" />
         <?php } ?>
     .......
    </head>
```